# How do I disable mouse swipe history?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, browsing, mouse-gestures

On my Chromebook, I get a feature where I swipe with two fingers to the left or right and I go forward or back a page in my history. Sometimes, it gets very irritating and I want to disable it. I use Chrome OS. I'm currently doing schoolwork, and I accidentally swiped to try to scroll to the left, not to change pages, and it changed pages!

Is there a way to disable it? Here is a screenshot:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16cz83JjlUGOeOlWzIjNaosbLTGwwFgHd/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to `chrome://flags`
- Search 'Overscroll' in the search bar
- Find 'Overscroll history navigation' in the results below
- Set it to 'Disabled'
- Close and reopen Chrome

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! 

Comment: Happy to help :)